Unable to connect to Ubuntu VM via Putty
I'm new to Ubuntu and I have a Windows machine. I am using Oracle VM Virtualbox and installed Ubuntu Linux server in it and using it. I am trying to connect to this Ubuntu server via Putty from my Windows machine, but I am unable to connect, and I get "Network error: Connection Refused" or "Network error: Connection timed out" error. I am listing down the all the stuff I did and tried in Ubuntu server:

I verified that SSH service is running in the server (Used sudo systemctl status ssh.service command, and it shows ssh is active:running result)
I verified that the ssh service is listening to port 22.
When I ran ifconfig in the ununtu, I get multiple network interfaces: one for loopback, one for enp0s3, and one for docker.
I tried with all the IPs from loopback/enp0s3/docker in Putty with port 22 (SSH) along with  "Connection > Data" - entering my ubuntu username for the Auto-login username, I am either getting "Network error: Connection Refused" or "Network error: Connection timed out" error (I don't know which IP to use with Putty, so tried with everything shown).
I even allowed VM Virtualbox Machine in my Windows Firewall as well.

My ubuntu server version is 22.04.4.
Am I missing something here, or using a wrong IP to connect from Putty? Please help.

The missing piece here is how you configured the VM's network adapter(s) - in particular, are you using a bridged or NAT virtual network?

I checked my Settings > Network > Adapter, it shows "NAT".
The other options which are displayed are:
Bridged Adapter,
Internal Network,
Host-only adapter,
Generic Driver,
NAT Network,
Cloud Network (EXPERIMENTAL),
Not attached.
Please let me know if any other option needs to be selected. I am using a Wi-Fi connection at my home to connect to internet.

If you are using NAT, then you will need to set up port forwarding - see for example How to configure VirtualBox port forwarding. If you switch to Bridged mode then you should be able to connect directly using the guest's IP address.

I followed the above guideline and configured the port forwarding for NAT in VirtualBox. I entered Host IP as 127.0.0.1, Host Port as 2222, Guest IP as 10.0.2.15, Guest Port as 22 and saved it. When I tested the forwarding rule as given in the ubuntu vm: "ssh -p2222 user@127.0.0.1", I get the error "ssh: connect to host 127.0.0.1 port 2222: connection refused".
